# Why does Spyder not pick up a global variable?

Tags: python, spyder

This is probably something obvious, but I'm confused.

I have a Python script test.py:

```
def t():
    print(a)

a = 1

t()
```

When I run it, it prints 1, as expected:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Dave/data/Code/Python/lib/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Dave/data/Code/Python/lib')
1
```

But when I then interactively type "a = 999" and run t() again, I expect it to print 999. But it prints 1. Why?

```
runfile('C:/Users/Dave/data/Code/Python/lib/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Dave/data/Code/Python/lib')
1

a = 999

t()
1
```

FWIW, I'm running iPython inside Spyder.

Am I correct to think this is strange and not what I should expect?

Screenshot (added):

[image]

Comment: What's `runfile`?  I expect what's happening is that the `a` inside the `test.py` module shadows the `a` that you're defining in the outer scope.

Comment: @Samwise I don't know. It's what gets printed when I hit the "run" button in the Spyder IDE. https://www.spyder-ide.org/

Comment: Without knowing how exactly that works I can't say for certain, but in general you should avoid using "global" variables (which usually aren't really global) like this.  It's almost always confusing and it almost never makes anything easier.

Comment: @samwise What you mean "shadows"? It happens with other variable names, too - not just 'a'.

Comment: I don't use it, but it looks like `runfile` is something specific to Spyder. It seems to behave as if it imported the file, so that `t` and `a` are in the namespace of the interactive shell, but `t` uses the global `a` of the module it's part of.

Comment: By doing `a = 999` you are simply assigning a new variable to the shell's scope. When you call `t()` it accesses the `a` in the module's scope which is not changed...

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) To properly solve this on Spyder, please see the answer I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same variables:

```
def t():
    print(id(a))

a = 1

t()
```

```
>>> runfile('C:/Users/Dave/data/Code/Python/lib/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Dave/data/Code/Python/lib')
xx

>>> a = 999
>>> print(id(a))
yy

>>> t()
xx
```

---

This is the default behavior of `runfile`. It run the code in different namespaces.

```
def runfile(filename=None, args=None, wdir=None, namespace=None, post_mortem=False, current_namespace=False):
```

Change the `current_namespace` to `True` if you want to run it in the current namespace.

Comment: I suppose somehow they're not the same variable, or this wouldn't be happening. But why?

Comment: Because the file you run is not copy-pasted in the interactive interpreter, but probably imported as a module, and global variables are global at the module level. So the `a` used by the `t` function is the one in its module. You could import it properly with something like `import <your_module_name>` - but check your directories, and refer to it with `your_module_name.a`. And you can see one more reason to not use global variables...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille but 't' is in the interactive namespace, so why isn't 'a' also?

Comment: `a` got imported at the same time as `t` (so at this time, `a` in your namespace referred to the `a` of the imported module), but you created a new `a` in your namespace that refers to `999` (in other words, you created an integer object with the value `999`, and made the name `a` refer to it. The global `a` from the imported module still refers to the value `1`). When you call `t()`, it looks up `a` in the module in which it is defined, so it gets the value `1`.